# Spring BootのRestTemplateでREST APIを実行しているがエラーが発生する

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, webapi, rest

InstagramのグラフAPIを、Spring BootのRestTemplateの中でコールしようとしているのですが、エラーが発生しており、解決方法をご教示いただきたいです。

エラーメッセージを見る限り、URIに含まれる波括弧 `{}` が原因ではないかと思っているのですが、いくつか試してみたのですが解決することができていません。
なお、ブラウザやターミナルから実行した場合にレスポンスが正常に返ってくることは確認しています。

実行環境
・IDE : IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.3 (Community Edition)
・Java 17
・Spring Boot 3.2.2

ブラウザやcurlでのレスポンス

```
{"business_discovery":{"followers_count":464946,"media_count":2193,"id":[ビジネスアカウント情報]},"id":[ビジネスアカウント情報]}
```

#### 試してみたこと

- `{` を `%7B` に変更、`}` を `%7D` に変更
- 以下のようにURL直指定に変更

  ```
  String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/[ビジネスアカウント情報]?fields=business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}&access_token=[アクセストークン]";
  ```

#### 参考サイト

Spring Bootリファレンス
https://spring.pleiades.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest

Instagram グラフAPIリファレンス
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-user

ItsApplication.java

```
package com.example.its;

import com.example.its.domain.instagram.InstagramAccountEntity;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ItsApplication {
    public static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ItsApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ItsApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("!test")
    public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/[ビジネスアカウント情報]")
                    .queryParam("fields", "business_discovery.username(bluebottle){followers_count,media_count}")
                    .queryParam("access_token", "[アクセストークン]");      
            String url = uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString();

            InstagramAccountEntity instagramAccountEntity = restTemplate.getForObject(url, InstagramAccountEntity.class);
            log.info(instagramAccountEntity.toString());
        };
    }
}
```

InstagramAccountEntity.java

```
package com.example.its.domain.instagram;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public record InstagramAccountEntity(BusinessDiscovery businessDiscovery, String id) {
}
```

BusinessDiscovery.java

```
package com.example.its.domain.instagram;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public record BusinessDiscovery(Long followers_count, Long media_count, String id) {
}
```

スタックトレースログ

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: "{"error":{"message":"Syntax error \"Expected end of string instead of \"\u0025\".\" at character 39: business_discovery.username(bluebottle)\u00257Bfollowers_count,media_count\u00257D","type":"OAuthException","code":2500,"fbtrace_id":"A9VWRptjuOlOiWI3MFe03Ma"}}"
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException.create(HttpClientErrorException.java:103) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:183) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:137) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:932) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:881) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:781) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:395) ~[spring-web-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at com.example.its.ItsApplication.lambda$run$0(ItsApplication.java:67) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.3.jar:6.1.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.2.jar:3.2.2]
    at com.example.its.ItsApplication.main(ItsApplication.java:25) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
            String url = uriComponentsBuilder.toUriString();
```

の `url` に設定されている実際の文字列を見てみてください。波カッコが [パーセントエンコード](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%91%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%87%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0) され `%7B` や `%7D` になっていると思います。

```java
            String url = uriComponentsBuilder.encode().build().toUriString();
            // あるいは今回の文字列は encode() しても結果が変わらないのは自明なので
            // String url = uriComponentsBuilder.build().toUriString();
```

で想定した動きになるのではないでしょうか。

ref:

- [`UriComponentsBuilder#toUriString()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#toUriString()) 及び [`encode()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.html#encode())

Answer (score 0):

ありがとうございます。

確かに元のコードでは波括弧がパーセントエンコードされていました。ご提示いただいた方法で想定した挙動になりました。

今後の方の参考のためですが、上記の変更をすると、「Not enough variable values available to expand 〜〜〜」というエラーが発生します。
これはurlに含まれる波括弧がプレースホルダーとして認識されたことでパースエラーになっています。

これを解決するために、以下のように指定しています。

```
String colulmns= "{followers_count,media_count}";
String url = uriComponentsBuilder.build().toUriString();
・・・
InstagramAccountEntity instagramAccountEntity = restTemplate.getForObject(url, InstagramAccountEntity.class, colulmns);
```

参考：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21819210/